# Find the value of $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{k}{n^2}\right )^{\frac{k}{n^2} +1} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

Compute limit of sum :

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{k}{n^2} \right)^{\dfrac{k}{n^2} +1} $$

**My Attempt :**

$$\Big( \dfrac{k}{n^2} \Big)^{\frac{k}{n^2} +1} = e^{\Big( \frac{k}{n^2} +1 \Big) \log\Big(\frac{k}{n^2}\Big)} = \Big( e^{\Big( \frac{k}{n^2} +1 \Big) }\Big)^{\log\Big(\frac{k}{n^2}\Big)} = \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \dfrac{k}{n} \Big( e^{\frac{k}{n^2}} \Big)^{\log (\frac{k}{n^2})}  $$

I am unable to move ahead, please help.

Comment: It's useful to use $x^x = e^{x\log(x)} = 1 + \mathcal{O}(x\log(x))$ as $x\to 0$ and note that all your "$x$'s" are small. The first term gives rise to $\sum k/n^2$ which you can evaluate and then you can try to estimate the error term and try to show that it goes to zero.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3735270, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/196095 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Crightarrow%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Cleft(%20%5Cfrac%7Bk%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%20%5Cright)%5E%7B%5Cdfrac%7Bk%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D%20%2B1%7D%24)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to solve my problem moving along with Winther's idea (thanks a lot) :

$\Big( \dfrac{k}{n^2} \Big)^{\frac{k}{n^2} +1} = e^{\Big( \frac{k}{n^2} +1 \Big) \log\Big(\frac{k}{n^2}\Big)} = \Big( e^{\Big( \frac{k}{n^2} +1 \Big) }\Big)^{\log\Big(\frac{k}{n^2}\Big)} = \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \dfrac{k}{n} \Big( e^{\frac{k}{n^2}} \Big)^{\log (\frac{k}{n^2})} $

$= \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \dfrac{k}{n} \Bigg(1 + \mathcal{O} \Big( \frac{k}{n^2}\log (\frac{k}{n^2}) \Big) \Bigg)  $

we want to use the given series expansion for small $x$ :

$x^x \sim \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} (x \log x)^k = 1 + x \log x + \frac{1}{2} x^2 \log^2 x + O(x^3 \log^3 x) .$

first term obviously gives :

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \dfrac{k}{n} = \int_0^1 xdx = \dfrac{1}{2}$

for second term we use :

$ \dfrac{k}{n^2} \mathcal{O} \Big( \frac{k}{n^2}\log (\dfrac{k}{n^2}) \Big) =  \Big[ \Big(\dfrac{k}{n^2}\Big)^2 \log \Big( \dfrac{k}{n^2} \Big) + ... \Big]$

where, $ n \cdot \Big(\dfrac{1}{n^2}\Big)^2 \log \Big( \dfrac{1}{n^2} \Big) < \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \Big(\dfrac{k}{n^2}\Big)^2 \log \Big( \dfrac{k}{n^2} \Big) < n \cdot \Big(\dfrac{n}{n^2}\Big)^2 \log \Big( \dfrac{n}{n^2} \Big)$

using squeez theorem, we see, both sides sum will go to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and similarly the higher order terms as well.

hence, answer is = $\dfrac{1}{2}$.